# pick next 24 hours job

Tags: mysql, sql

retrieve next 24 hours details from the table

i read one thread, same question here

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243713/php-mysql-query-most-popular-in-last-24-hours)

but small diff is , my field name is jdate is the varachar, but they are used the datetime data type format,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use str_to_date before :)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

so the sql like :

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(my_field,'myformat') > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Comment: Sorry , this same query for sql also or somthing diff

Comment: i appalogies, i have two database, one is sql and mysql, so i need for mssql also